# Drupal removing javascript from Full HTML link

Tags: javascript, drupal, onclick

I am new to Drupal and am trying to create a node (let's call it child) that will only really be accessed when clicked on from another node (we'll call it parent). When closing the child window, I want to parent window to refresh.

Outside of Drupal, that's easy:

```
<a onclick="window.close(); window.opener.location.reload();" href="#">Click to close this window</a>
```

However, when I type this into the body of a node using Full HTML, it still strips the onclick text from my post. How can I include javascript in the body of a node like this? Is there a special module I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind. Answered my own question: Use the PHP input filter instead of full HTML and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize input filters and make your own, to provide more options.

Using the PHP input filter is not a good idea unless you really want to input PHP.
Also you might not want to give all admins that should make links with JavsScript access to writing PHP code on the site.